# Java - What is the correct signature for this generic class?

Tags: java, generics

Here is a class I have :

```
public class ProxyDAO<T extends DAO<? extends Model>> implements DAO<? extends Model> {
   ...
}
```

The compiler complains that `A supertype may not implement a wildcard`.

I have tried this:

```
public class ProxyDAO<T extends DAO<? extends Model>> implements DAO<Model> {
   ...
}
```

But subclasses of Model are now not allowed.

How can I tell the compiler that ProxyDAO implements the DAO interface and that this interface would be accept a Model class or any subclasses or Model ?

**DAO.java**

```
public interface DAO<T extends Model> {
    T findByPK(Object pk);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
public class ProxyDAO<T extends Model> implements DAO<T>
```

And if you need to allow for supclasses of DAO:

```
public class ProxyDAO<T extends Model, V extends DAO<T>> implements DAO<T>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something as

```
class ProxyDao<M extends Model, T extends Dao<M>> implements Dao<M> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood. In `implements` clause there is no possibility to set undefined type except as using two generic parameters. You can set there actual type like `Model`. So this code will work:

```
class Model{}

class SubModel extends Model{}

interface DAO<T extends Model> {
    T findByPK(T pk);
}

class ProxyDAO<T extends DAO<? extends Model>> implements DAO<Model> {

    public ProxyDAO() {
        findByPK(new SubModel());
    }

    @Override
    public Model findByPK(Model pk) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```